# remove site collection link from top link bar

Tags: 2013, navigation, top-link-bar

I've just created a site collection, and then subsequently activated the publishing site collection feature on it, so that I can have the fancy Navigation options. However I've noticed (i dont know how i never noticed this before) that a link to the root web of the site collection appears in the top link bar, but doesn't appear in the Navigation page. Is there a way to remove this link or am I stuck with it?

[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]

Comment: I also have same requirements. Can anyone provide solution to this ?

Comment: Upvote my question if you would like an answer to it as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the following CSS code to hide it:

```
.ms-breadcrumb-top ul.ms-core-listMenu-root>li.static>a.static.menu-item{
  display:none;
}
```

You can add the above to the alternate CSS file for the site collection.

Hope this can help.

Comment: ...dont know why i never thought of this before.

Comment: great solution :) It helps me a lot, because I found noway to remove link to my site collection. Thank you